# Is there a way to have dimension shown in fractions?

Tags: dimensions

I can enter dimensions in fractions but then can only see dimensions ofr objects in decimals. I live in the US and I'm using blender to create build plans. For the plans to be useful to people in the trades dimensions need to be shown in fractions.

Comment: AFAIK only thousandths are possible in UI eg `5" 375thou` for five and three eighths inches.  Surely this is a simple by sight conversion. (even if shown as a decimal)  I imagine  if not able to convert decimals to fractions renders the plans as a blender file un-useful, the user may also have difficulty with using  blender itself.,  If you are rendering the plans for distribution,  then  convert output of  dimensions  to required units,  fractions

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not possible at the moment to have something like 5 3/8". [Request this feature](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/) or try to find a Python script. And it's possible to import, with an  app, .obj files to AutoCad and do the measuring there with fractions supported. Blender's primary goal is not architecture/housing.